# How to bind hard coded value to datsource of MatTableDataSource?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-table

I am using reactive model.and angular material.
I want to display mat table of student. I am binding values hardcoded to table.but its not working .

i tried example of angular material exactly.

user.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="sno">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sno}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="sname">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Student Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sname}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

user.ts

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['sno', 'sname', 'age'];

  dataSource : MatTableDataSource<Student>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStudList();
  }

  getStudList(){
    const ELEMENT_DATA: Student[] = [
      {sno: 1, sname: 'durga', age: 26},
      {sno: 2, sname: 'gauri', age: 25},
      {sno: 3, sname: 'laxmi', age: 24},
    ];
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  }
}
```

It is giving me dataSource isn't property of mat-table.

Comment: have you imported ``MatTableModule`` in your module ?

Comment: @CruelEngine yes..Due to short this code i didnt show it

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz example for your problem ? Here is one i created and has no issues : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trutbc

Comment: i dont about stackblitz .. i am trying example in your way again thank you